# special characters not working in bootstrap tooltip title data-html true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have issues with bootstrap tooltip title when I'm using `data-html="true"` for the title. I'm using html tags in tooltip title for font styles and line break. For this I used `data-html="true"`. However when i used < (less than) icon, tooltip title text not displayed after less than icon (<)

```
<html><head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="container">
             <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
             <a href="#" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="title with <br /> special character <less than over me Hooray!">Tooltip </a>
          </div>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
             });
          </script>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like your example is malformed and not highlighted properly. Also, i'd be a good idea to use code playground-site e.g. https://codepen.io/ to set up an example.

Comment: You mean you want a < to show in the tooltip text? Then use `&lt;`.

Comment: Mt Lister, thanks for response. The tootlip title will come dynamically not static text.

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <html><head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="container">
             <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
             <a href="#" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title='title with <br/> special character < less than over me Hooray!'>Tooltip </a>
          </div>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
             });
          </script>
       </body>
</html>`
```

Just give space between special character and word. Othere it will parse as html tags or use `&lt`.

Comment: thanks sumesh, but the tooltip title be dynamically placed.

Comment: @BaluP find and replace the possible special characters using string manipulation functions

Comment: in this demo it worked, will see how it will be in the real time case,  as manipulation function should not disturb the other html tags like <br /> & <b>

Comment: @BaluP Use unicodes corresponding to special characters for java,javascript programs. Refer https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html